# Python unzip AES-128 encrypted file

Tags: python, aes, zip

Is there a way to decompress an AES-128 encrypte file directly with python, since ZipFile throws a Bad Password error. If i use 7zip it works, so the password is correct, but then again 7zip needs to be installed as a dependency.

What i tried:

```
from ZipFile import ZipFile
zip = ZipFile('test.zip')
zip.extractall(pwd='password')
```

This throws the Bad Password exception.

Checking the file with 7zip

```
7z l -slt test.zip
```

This returns:

```
Encrypted = +
Method = pkAES-128 Deflate
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The zipfile module from the Python standard library supports only CRC32 encrypted zip files (see here: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/71adf21421d9/Lib/zipfile.py#l420 ). So, there is no way around some 3rd party dependency.

The easiest way would be to just install 7zip and call the commandline utility `7z` using the `subprocess` module from the standard lib:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["7z", "x", "-ppassword", "test.zip"])
```

Another option would be the python module "PyLzma" which can also handle AES encrypted 7zip archives: https://github.com/fancycode/pylzma . It doesn't directly support decrypting classic zip files but you could use its routines to write your own decompressor function.

Comment: Could you please help on How to read the output of this subprocess.call? @Bernhard Kausler

Answer (score 9):

You can use the library *pyzipper*: https://github.com/danifus/pyzipper. It works nearly the same as Python's [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html):

```py
import pyzipper

with pyzipper.AESZipFile('my_archive.zip') as f:
    f.pwd = b'myPassword'
    print(f.infolist())
    file_content = f.read('testfile.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [stream-unzip](https://github.com/uktrade/stream-unzip) to decrypt AES encrypted ZIP files (full disclosure: written by me)

```py
from stream_unzip import stream_unzip

def zipped_chunks(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        while chunk := f.read(65536):
           yield chunk

for file_name, file_size, unzipped_chunks in stream_unzip(zipped_chunks('test.zip'), password=b'password'):
    for chunk in unzipped_chunks:
        print(chunk)
```