# How to open password protected zip file in Python 3

Tags: python, encryption, zip

I'm trying to open a password protected zip file in Python. However, I'm completely stuck!

I've gone through the python documentation on zip files, but I can't find anything for opening one that is password protected.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

```
path = "some_file.zip"
password = "example123"

# How do I add the password parameter?
ZipFile.extractall(path)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all yet? Any code you can post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html:

```
ZipFile.extractall([path[, members[, pwd]]])
```

Extract all members from the archive to the current working directory. `path` specifies a different directory to extract to. `members` is optional and must be a subset of the list returned by `namelist()`. `pwd` is the password used for encrypted files.

Works on Python 3 too: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

Comment: This applies only to legacy weak encryption. For current strong encryption see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553150/python-unzip-aes-128-encrypted-file