# Load several zip files of one folder with password in one pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, zip

I have a folder, where I have several zip files saved, e.g.:

```
Folder path: C:\Users\FolderA
Files in the folder: A.Zip, B.Zip,....,Z.Zip
```

this zip files are all protected with the same password: lordoftherings

How Can i load all files in that zip files into one dataframe (note that every zip file contains exactly one csv file).

So far I only know how can i load [multiple csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52289386/loading-multiple-csv-files-of-a-folder-into-one-dataframe). And I know how I can load a zip file:

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('C:/...')
dfClearstream = pd.read_csv(zf.open('....csv'), sep=';')
```

So the desired outcome would be one dataframe in pandas.

Answer (score 1):

According to your answer, [multiple csv loading example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52289386/loading-multiple-csv-files-of-a-folder-into-one-dataframe), and [open password protected zip file example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631629/how-to-open-password-protected-zip-file-in-python-3), you can make codes like below:

If you have A.csv in A.zip, B.csv in B.zip, ...

```py
import glob
import pandas as pd
import zipfile

password = b'lordoftherings' # Set password

zipfiles = glob.glob("C:\Users\FolderA\*.zip") # Get list of zip files
zfs = [(zipfile.ZipFile(f), f.split("\\")[-1].split(".")[0] + '.csv') for f in zipfiles]
# Get ZipFile object and csv file name for each zip file

dfs = [pd.read_csv(zf.open(filename, 'r', password), header=None, sep=';') for zf, filename in zfs]
# Unzip zip file with password, read csv files

salesdata = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I get the error: KeyError: "There is no item named 'A_02.csv' in the archive"

Comment: You need to specify the structure of your zip file. If the contents of your zip file is like
<Folder - file> you need to add folder name to the filename while unzipping.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list with dataframes and the `concat` them with:

```py
dfs = []

with zipfile.ZipFile('my_zip.zip') as zf:
    for file in zf.namelist():
        dfs.append(pd.read_csv(zf.open(file), sep=';'))

df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: I have several zip files in one folder and not several files in one zip