# How can I extract a zip file which is password protected (using 128-bit AES encryption as the encryption method) in Python?

Tags: python, encryption, zip

I'd like to extract some files from a 128-bit AES encrypted zip file. I've tried using the built-in Python module but as far as I can tell, it only supports CRC32 as an encryption method.

The archive in question was created with [the DotNetZip library](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) with the `Encryption` property set to `Zip::EncryptionAlgorithm::WinZipAes128`

This is the snippet I've tried which gives me:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('MyZip.ZIP') as zf:
    zf.extractall(pwd=b'password')
```

Which gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Extract.py", line 5, in <module>
    zf.extractall(pwd=b'password')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 1240, in extractall
    self.extract(zipinfo, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 1228, in extract
    return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 1290, in _extract_member
    with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 1207, in open
    raise RuntimeError("Bad password for file", name)
RuntimeError: ('Bad password for file', <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x0000000002B02E88>)
```

How can I extract the contents?

Comment: Why all the down-votes? I've re-phrased the question a little if that was the issue?

Comment: Re-phrased my question :)

Comment: Hmmm.. not sure why I did't spot this before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553150/python-unzip-aes-128-encrypted-file