# Opening a Zip file (password protected) giving error 'Bad password' even though the password is correct

Tags: python

Opening a Zip file (password protected) giving error 'Bad password' even though the password is correct. Tried converting the password to bytes and printed to check the password

Opening a Zip file (password protected) giving error 'Bad password' even though the password is correct. Tried converting the password to bytes and printed to check the password. password is converted to "b'password'".I tried unprotected zip files opening correctly. There seems to be a problem with password protected files only.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as file:
        file.extractall(pwd = bytes(pswd, 'utf-8'))
```

> Expected result:
>   Password is correct and it should open the file.
>
> Error message:
>   Bad password for file

Comment: Your zip file might be AES encrypted. In that case, the zipfile module does not support it. You can use the pyzipper module as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553150/python-unzip-aes-128-encrypted-file).

Answer (score 0):

I used pyzipper and it worked for me.

here is the code:
pwd = bytes(pswd, 'utf-8')

with pyzipper.AESZipFile(file_name) as f:
    f.pwd = pwd

I tried the other suggested solution also - using subprocess calls. 
As I am quite new to the Python and still have to explore things. It would be of great help, If I can provide some more details of subprocess calls.

Thank you all.