# How to extract a password protected zip file that is zipped using PKWARE SecureZip in Python? (Windows 10)

Tags: python, unzip, password-protection, pkware

I'm trying to extract contents of **password protected** zip files that have been zipped using PKWARE SecureZip in Python.
Modules that I've tried already are zipfile and pyzipper. But methods of these modules always return 'NotImplementedError: strong encryption (flag bit 6)'.

```
from pyzipper

with ZipFile('Test.zip') as tz:
    tz.extractall(pwd=bytes('testpass', 'utf-8'))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Pradeep/Python Workspace/Sandbox/EvoFileDownloader.py", line 4, in <module>
    tz.extractall(pwd=bytes('testpass', 'utf-8'))
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\zipfile.py", line 1616, in extractall
    self._extract_member(zipinfo, path, pwd)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\zipfile.py", line 1669, in _extract_member
    with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\zipfile.py", line 1500, in open
    raise NotImplementedError("strong encryption (flag bit 6)")
NotImplementedError: strong encryption (flag bit 6)
```

I have tried to work around this by checking for ways to extract these zip files from the command prompt.
However, I don't see 'pkzipc.exe' in my installation directory (as explained in [this](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/manuals/pkzipcli14.pdf) document).

P.S: I do not have admin rights required to install additional software on my work computer (on which I'm trying this extraction).

Can anyone help me with a solution for this?

Comment: Can you attach a sample zip file such that we can test it?

Comment: @Molitoris I would advise to not download and open up files given in examples. I would instead ask of a way to replicate the file / archive via code or one provided from a reputable source.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python unzip AES-128 encrypted file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553150/python-unzip-aes-128-encrypted-file)

Comment: Especially take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15554407/2018369) answer

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15554407/2018369) solution requires 7zip to be installed, but as I mentioned in the question, I'm attempting the extraction in a work computer for which I do not have admin rights (needed to install any new software).

Comment: I downloaded the 7zip exe and executed the following command:
`7za x -ptestpass "C:\Users\prade\Desktop\Test.zip"`

However, this returns the following error:
`Extracting archive: C:\Users\prade\Desktop\Test.zip`
 
`ERROR: Unsupported Method : Test\1.jpg`
`ERROR: Unsupported Method : Test\2.jpg`
`ERROR: Unsupported Method : Test\3.jpg`
 
`Sub items Errors: 3`
 
`Archives with Errors: 1`
 
`Sub items Errors: 3`

1.jpg, 2.jpg and 3.jpg are files within Test.zip

Comment: So the key information here, that I missed is that it was zipped using PKWARE SecureZip. So I guess the only way to unzip is to use this particular softrware. I know it's enterprise class software and you might not have license for it purchased. If that is the case consider using free of charge [PKWARE Zip reader](https://www.pkware.com/zip-reader) for extracting. And... I dont know if it's possible to use it without instalation and later to use command line version in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you are trying to decompress was compressed using commercial software PKWARE SecureZip. This is not standard zip archive so none of free zip software/libraries can extract it.

If you want to decompress it from your app/script there are 2 possible ways. Both requires having commercial PKWARE product installed.

Assuming that you have license to use it I guess the best idea would be to use [SecureZIP SDK library provided by PKWARE](https://support.pkware.com/home/pkzip/developer-tools/sdk-toolkit-s/securezip-toolkit-for-windows). This is not python library so you will have to implement a python wrapper for using this sdk.
[Description of this SecureZIP toolkit for Windows](https://support.pkware.com/home/pkzip/developer-tools/sdk-toolkit-s/securezip-toolkit-for-windows) mentions that it uses Microsoft’s Crypto API so perhaps [windows.crypto](http://hakril.github.io/PythonForWindows/build/html/crypto.html) python library might be usefull.

Second approach would require installing free-of-charge [PKWARE zip reader](https://www.pkware.com/zip-reader) and invoking this app with apropriate parameters (assuming it has any command line interface) from your python script using `subprocess.call` similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15554407/2018369)